# AttributeError when scoring sklearn pipeline with custom transformer subclass but not when fitting

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, scikit-learn, pipeline

I'm having issues understanding how to create a subclass of an sklearn transformer. I would like to apologise for the long code sample, I tried to make a minimum reproducible, but was unable to recreate the error. Hopefully you'll see that most of the code sample is me documenting.

The transformer is described below in the code snippet.

```
class PCAVarThreshSelector(PCA):
"""
Description
-----------
Selects the columns that can explain a certain percentage of the variance in a data set

Authors
-------
Eden Trainor

Notes
-----
1. PCA has a principole component limit of 4459 components, no matter how many more features you put into
it this is a hrad limit of how many components it will return to you.

"""

def __init__(self, 
             n_components=None, 
             copy=True, 
             whiten=False, 
             svd_solver='auto', 
             tol=0.0, 
             iterated_power='auto', 
             random_state=None, 
             explained_variance_thresh = 0.8):


    super(PCAVarThreshSelector, self).__init__(n_components, copy, whiten, svd_solver, tol, iterated_power, random_state)


    self.explained_variance_thresh = explained_variance_thresh

def find_nearest_index(self, array, value):
    """
    Description
    -----------
    Finds the index of the coefficient in an array nearest a certain value.


    Args
    ----
    array: np.ndarray, (number_of_componants,)
        Array containing coeffficients 

    value: int,
        Index of coefficient in array closset to this value is found.


    Returns
    -------
    index: int,
        Index of coefficient in array closest to value.
    """

    index = (np.abs(array - value)).argmin()

    return index

def fit(self, X, y = None):
    """
    Description
    -----------
    Fits the PCA and calculates the index threshold index of the cumulative explained variance ratio array.


    Args
    ----
    X: DataFrame, (examples, features)
        Pandas DataFrame containing training example features

    y: array/DataFrame, (examples,)
        (Optional) Training example labels

    Returns
    -------
    self: PCAVarThreshSelector instance
        Returns transfromer instance with fitted instance variables on training data.
    """

    #PCA fit the dataset
    super(PCAVarThreshSelector, self).fit(X)

    #Get the cumulative explained variance ratio array (ascending order of cumulative variance explained)
    cumulative_EVR = self.explained_variance_ratio_.cumsum()

    #Finds the index corresponding to the threshold amount of variance explained
    self.indx = self.find_nearest_index(array = cumulative_EVR, 
                                    value = self.explained_variance_thresh)


    return self

def transform(self, X):
    """
    Description
    -----------        
    Selects all the principle components up to the threshold variance.


    Args
    ----
    X: DataFrame, (examples, features)
        Pandas DataFrame containing training example features


    Returns
    -------
    self: np.ndarray, (examples, indx)
        Array containing the minimum number of principle componants required by explained_variance_thresh.
    """

    all_components =  super(PCAVarThreshSelector, self).transform(X) #To the sklean limit

    return all_components[:, :self.indx]
```

I tested this class with my data and it works as expected, in a simple pipeline with a RobustScaler infront. In this simple pipeline the class will fit and transform as expected.

Then I put the simple pipeline into another pipeline, with an estimator, hoping to .fit() and .score() the pipe:

```
model_pipe = Pipeline([('ppp', Pipeline([('rs', RobustScaler()),
                                    ('pcavts', PCAVarThreshSelector(whiten = True))])),
                  ('lin_reg', LinearRegression())])
```

The pipeline fits without error. However when I try to score it i get an AttributeError:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-92-cf336db13fe1> in <module>()
----> 1 model_pipe.score(X_test, y_test)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\metaestimators.py in <lambda>(*args, **kwargs)
    113 
    114         # lambda, but not partial, allows help() to work with update_wrapper
--> 115         out = lambda *args, **kwargs: self.fn(obj, *args, **kwargs)
    116         # update the docstring of the returned function
    117         update_wrapper(out, self.fn)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py in score(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    484         for name, transform in self.steps[:-1]:
    485             if transform is not None:
--> 486                 Xt = transform.transform(Xt)
    487         score_params = {}
    488         if sample_weight is not None:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py in _transform(self, X)
    424         for name, transform in self.steps:
    425             if transform is not None:
--> 426                 Xt = transform.transform(Xt)
    427         return Xt
    428 

<ipython-input-88-9153ece48646> in transform(self, X)
    114         all_components =  super(PCAVarThreshSelector, self).transform(X) #To the sklean limit
    115 
--> 116         return all_components[:, :self.indx]
    117 

AttributeError: 'PCAVarThreshSelector' object has no attribute 'indx'
```

I initially thought it was to do with how I have called super() in the class. As per [this](https://thingspython.wordpress.com/2010/09/27/another-super-wrinkle-raising-typeerror/) blog post, I think that the class is being re-initiated when the pipeline is being .score()-ed, hence the attribute created in the fit method no longer exists when scored.
I have tried a few other methods of calling the methods of the parent class including: super().method, PCA.method(), as well as the method suggested in the blog post but all give the same error.

I think that maybe the blog's solution is specific to Python 2, whilst my code is in Python 3.

However when trying to reproduce this error in a minimum reproducable for this Question, i no longer got the error.

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression
from sklearn.base import TransformerMixin, BaseEstimator
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

X, y = make_regression() #Just some dummy regression data for demonstrative purposes.

class BaseTransformer(TransformerMixin, BaseEstimator):

    def __init__(self):
        print("Base Init")

    def fit(self, X, y = None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        return X

class DerivedTransformer(BaseTransformer):

    def __init__(self):
        super(DerivedTransformer, self).__init__()
        print("Dervied init")

    def fit(self, X, y = None):
        super(DerivedTransformer, self).fit(X, y)
        self.new_attribute = 0.0001
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        output = super(DerivedTransformer, self).transform(X)
        output += self.new_attribute

        return output

base_pipeline = Pipeline([('base_transformer', BaseTransformer()),
              ('linear_regressor', LinearRegression())])

derived_pipeline = Pipeline([('derived_transformer', DerivedTransformer()),
              ('linear_regressor', LinearRegression())])
```

The above code ran as expected without an error. I'm at a loss. Can anyone help me solve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats because you havent overrode (implemented) the `fit_transform()` method.

Just adding the following part to your `PCAVarThreshSelector` will solve the problem:

```
def fit_transform(self, X, y=None):
    return self.fit(X, y).transform(X)
```

**Reason**: Pipeline will try to first call the [`fit_transform()`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.base.TransformerMixin.html#sklearn.base.TransformerMixin.fit_transform) method on all the steps (excluding the last one of cource).

This `fit_transform()` method is just a shorthand for calling `fit()` and then `transform()` and is defined like how I defined above.

But in some cases, like `PCA`, or `CountVectorizer` etc in scikit-learn, this method is implemented differently to make the processing faster, because:

- checking / validating (and conversion) of data to appropriate form is done only once when compared to checking the data in `fit()` and then checking it again in `transform()`
- some other repetitive tasks can be streamlined easily

Since you inherited from PCA, when you call `model_pipe.fit()`, it uses the `fit_transform()` from PCA and hence never goes to the `fit()` method you defined (and hence your class object never contains any `indx` attribute.

But when you call `score()`, only the `transform()` is called on all the intermediate steps of the pipeline and goes to your implemented `transform()`. Hence the error.

Your example about BaseTransformer and DerivedTransformer can be made reproducible for your problem if you implement the `fit_transform()` in `BaseTransformer` a little differently.

Comment: You angel! Worked like a charm, very well explained, thank you for taking the time!